# Python requests module import error

Tags: python, python-requests

I have installed python requests module. I used standard `pip install requests`, the install was successful but it does not work at all. I am not able to import this module to any script file. I always get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Rzeczy Mariusza\Python\aaaa.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests
  File "D:\Programy\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "D:\Programy\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 12, in <module>
    import cgi
  File "D:\Programy\Python34\lib\cgi.py", line 39, in <module>
    from email.parser import FeedParser
  File "D:\Programy\Python34\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "D:\Programy\Python34\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "D:\Programy\Python34\lib\email\message.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email import utils
  File "D:\Programy\Python34\lib\email\utils.py", line 40, in <module>
    from email.charset import Charset
  File "D:\Programy\Python34\lib\email\charset.py", line 15, in <module>
    import email.quoprimime
  File "D:\Programy\Python34\lib\email\quoprimime.py", line 44, in <module>
    from string import ascii_letters, digits, hexdigits
ImportError: cannot import name 'ascii_letters'
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

It is strange, that when I am using IDLE I am able to import it (the module) without any problem. I run `Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32` if that info helps.

Comment: if you run `from string import ascii_letters` from a python3.4 shell what happens?

Comment: Have you multiple python versions installed? If you installed another version than 3.4 last, double-click or python yourscript.py won't open it with version 3.4 so requests may not be installed.

Comment: I do not have any other version installed than python 3.4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This usually means that you have a script called `string.py` in the same folder from which you execute it, and it messes up the imports.

If it is in fact the case, consider renaming it.

Comment: It does not have to be in the same folder, it just has to be in the path.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, valid point. Is it common, though, to have .py files in path?

Comment: That was the case. It is the trap of naming simple test files, as simple as `string.py`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I mean anywhere python looks for files before it gets to the builtins, if you ran the script from a directory where the parent had a string.py file it would import from  that, the string.py could be anywhere. The way to check is `import string; string.__file__`, that will tell you exactly what is being imported

Comment: I see, `print(string.__file__)` gives me path to the 'trap' file. It is good trick to know.

Comment: great tips ,i had the same package name as string ,thanks .